# Catch Multiple Exception

Tags: python, api, rest, exception, try-catch

I am writing an api.

```
from rest_framework import exceptions
```

class XYZ(APIView):

```
authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication, ]
permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, ]
api_view = ['GET']

def get(self, request):
    try:
        payer_data = validate_payer(db=db,request =request,payer = payer,userid = userid)            
        BODY OF API
    except Exception as e:
        print("---",e)
        manager.create_from_exception(e)
        return Response(AppResponse.msg(request, 400, 'Something went wrong.', 0, 0, 0), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

def validate_payer(db,request,payer,userid):
    organisations = ReportUtils.get_payer_and_company(db,request =request,userid = userid,payer=True)
    if len(organisations) == 0:
        raise exceptions.NotAcceptable(AppResponse.msg(request, 406, 'No payer associated with the user.', 0, 0, 0))
```

Now I want like if the exception is raised from validate_payer function then it should not come to except block in class XYZ(APIView) and when any other exception occurs because of body of pi then it should go to except block and return the bad request. ?

Comment: Wrap the single line in a `try`/`except` block that catches the exception you don't want to handle in the existing block.

Comment: I didn't get it. Could you please try to explain by example .

Comment: Looking at it more closely you could just take that one line out of the `try` block.

Comment: No I can't get that one line out of that try block as there is code above that line and below that line which is related to that line.

Comment: A try block is not a kind of namespace. If you put that line before the `try` it would only take it out of the exception catching.

Comment: Yes correct But if I take that line out of the try block then I have to put one try/except block before that line and one try/except block after that line, So isn't it bad way of writing a code by keeping two try/except blocks ?

Comment: I gave you a solution for the code you showed us. I can not take into account what you are hiding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use the **isinstance** built-in function.

```
def get(self, request):
try:
    payer_data = validate_payer(db=db,request =request,payer = payer,userid = userid)            
    BODY OF API
except Exception as e:
        if isinstance(e,exceptions.NotAcceptable):
            raise
        elif isinstance(e,exceptions.PermissionDenied):
            raise
        else:
            manager.create_from_exception(e)
            return Response(AppResponse.msg(request, 400, 'Something went wrong.', 0, 0, 0), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

So if the exception is of class NotAcceptable or PermissionDenied it will raise the exception again otherwise it will give common message **Something Went wrong** with status code **400**

Answer (score 0):

`Try / Except` blocks in python can have multiple except clauses through which the raised exception falls through until it hits the first clause that matches.

For a single exception that should re-raise (or requires other specific handling) instead of being handled by the Exception handler the following code should work.

```
def get(self, request):
    try:
        payer_data = validate_payer(db=db,request =request,payer = payer,userid = userid)            
        # BODY OF API
    except exceptions.NotAcceptable:
        # Handle NotAcceptable.
        raise
    except Exception as e:
        # Handle all other exceptions.
        manager.create_from_exception(e)
        return Response(AppResponse.msg(request, 400, 'Something went wrong.', 0, 0, 0), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
```

If multiple exceptions require the same exception handler the exception class can be replaced by a tuple of multiple exception classes.

```
def get(self, request):
    try:
        payer_data = validate_payer(db=db,request =request,payer = payer,userid = userid)            
        # BODY OF API
    except (exceptions.NotAcceptable, exceptions.PermissionDenied):
        # Handle NotAcceptable and PermissionDenied.
        raise
    except Exception as e:
        # Handle all other exceptions.
        manager.create_from_exception(e)
        return Response(AppResponse.msg(request, 400, 'Something went wrong.', 0, 0, 0), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
```

**NOTE**: `except Exception` will always match every exception derived from it, so it should always be placed last.